# Have a variable number of parametres to load a variable number of images at the same time

Tags: java, image, parameters

I have a Image that I imported in a different class:

```
static ImageIcon grassSprite1 = new ImageIcon("Images/Sprite/grass.png");
static Image grass1 = grassSprite1.getImage();
```

What I want to do now is draw this Image on a JFrame that I created which would look something like this:

```
drawImages(Graphics g){
     Graphics2D sprite = (Graphics2D) g;

     sprite.drawImage(GetSpriteImage.grass1, posX1, posY1, null);
     sprite.drawImage(GetSpriteImage.grass1, posX2, posY2, null);
     sprite.drawImage(GetSpriteImage.grass1, posX3, posY3, null);
     sprite.drawImage(GetSpriteImage.grass1, posX4, posY4, null);
     //draw the Image alot of times on multiple coordinates
}
```

Is it possible to create a class that requests a dynamic number of parametres?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
//Pseudocode

MultipleImages{

    public multipleImages(Image spriteImage, int int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, ..., int xn, int yn){

        for (i = 1, i < (number of x and y coordinates), i++){

            drawImage(spriteImage, xi, yi)
            //draws Image with coordinates 
            //x1, y1
            //x2, y2
            //...
            //xn, yn

        }
}
```

Which I can create a instance like this off:

```
multipleImages grass = new multipleImages(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, ..., xn, yn)
```

working with "n = any natual number".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an int array as a parameter instead. This would allow you to get (practically) as many ints as you want.

```
public multipleImages(Image spriteImage, int[] coords) {
    for (i = 0, i < coords.length, i+=2) {
        drawImage(spriteImage, coords[i], coords[i+1]);
    }
}
```

Although you should probably also check to make sure the array has an even number of elements and handle it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to create methods(constructors too) with dynamic amount of parameters. Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) for Arbitrary Number of Arguments. You can achieve desired effect using such constructor:

```
public Points(Point... points)
{
    //Use points as array.
    points[0].x;
    //...
}
```

Object of this class can be instantiated in that way:

```
Points points = new Points(new Point(0, 0), new Point(1, 1));
```